# Get collision state of model without contact sensor

Tags: gazebo-plugin, collision, ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone.
I am wondering if it is possible to check the collision state of a urdf-model in Gazebo without contact sensor.
For example, can I implement a world plugin where show which 'model:link' contacts another 'model:link'?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21841/get-collision-state-of-model-without-contact-sensor/) by [mkro0616](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8193/mkro0616/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could subscribe to `~/physics/contacts` and check for the contacts you want.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1